# API to creating a new user in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement an API which allows creating a new user in django.
I'm also using django-rest-frameowrk, if that helps.

I've tried the following with an admin user:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Token aa294c745214d18f392f5f96f2d2278921e11d74' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username":"dan"}' http://localhost:8000/api/users/
```

But I'm getting the response `{"detail": "Method 'POST' not allowed."}.`

Is this the right approach?

I might go for OAuth later, but right now I'm just looking to implement a simple API which will allow registering new users on the fly from multiple devices. I'd like to add the user's token to the response when the user is created, so each device can store the generated token for use later.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was the right approach, but I had the `User` viewset defined incorrectly:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

with the correct definition being

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```